# Is this transom window installation done properly?

Tags: doors, carpentry, door-frame, glass

He was to install double pre-hung doors to convert our den area into a room, but then realized the glass he had ordered for the transom was too tall. He cut vertically into the wall (there's a wooden beam running - not sure if it's a header - framing the top of the den opening) to make enough headroom for the excess height of glass.

He then divided the transom's frame parallel to the glass, installed half the transom frame, installed the glass by stabbing its top edge into the wall cavity above the door, and then sandwiched the glass with the other half of the transom frame. Attaching pics/vids, but it doesn't look too great. I know it will have the mouldings to cover it up, but he still had to cut into the metal corner piece holding the curve of the wall, as well as into the drywall/wall/wood itself itself.

He realized it was his mistake and offered that if we ever wanted to remove the door frame, he'd come in and patch up the drywall. Though the wood is already altered.

**corner where the sandwiching can be seen, and the glass enters the wall**

[image]

**front view**

[image]

**back view**

[image]

**close up view of transom and wood blocks pinning transom frame to ceiling**

[image]

My concerns are:

Would this be a cut into a critical structural piece of the house? Not entirely sure, but this is along a den opening on the first floor of our 2-story house

Will the transom be stable held together like this? The wooden sandwiching parts of the transom frame aren't exactly super thick, and the front portion is only about an inch or two thick. Additionally, the 3 wood pieces he nailed in (see close up view) are quite small and don't really dig into the wood above

Does the glass have a strong chance of falling out? It's about 95" wide, and no other supports in the transom. He says it will not but I'm doubtful

I am told he will use shims to hold the 'sandwiched transom' in place from the sides of the door frame. But still not sure.

Any advice is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: How far up did he cut into the header? (Phrased another way, how much glass was sticking up out of the modified frame?)

Comment: Did he actually cut into anything structural?  It looks like there's still sheetrock at the top of the opening right above the transom.

Comment: Hopefully that's not a structural wall.  That door looks too small for the opening...

Comment: The first picture clearly shows the corner bead folded up into the wall cavity. This is inconsistent with removing part of any header. Regarding the header, I edited "He suggested we could cut vertically" to "He cut vertically." In retrospect, the contractor may have discovered it was hollow and folded the corner bead up without the OP present to learn that there was no header (structural or non-) after all. I think, then, that the "critical structural piece" bit should be removed also, but maybe that's just my face-saving instinct talking. OP? You there? Can you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell whether the header was critically modified. If the glass just slots between header components it's probably fine. If not, please provide more detail about what exactly was cut.

The transom is probably stable enough. There are multiple full-length lateral members. The issue for me is more the potential for noise due to rattling when the door is operated. You'll want to be sure the stops holding the glass are snug or padded.

I can't see how the glass could fall out. It's fully entrapped. A lot would have to go wrong for it to come loose in a dangerous or costly manner.

Plenty of shims should be used, with appropriate fasteners through the frame, but *only on the sides*. The head should not be shimmed as settling could result in binding of the door, etc.

The damage to the metal corner bead isn't really a concern since it'll all be buried with moldings. I often completely remove bead in such situations to reduce the wall thickness, which is usually swollen at the bead area.

This is an awkward situation, and the ideal fix would be to have the glass cut down. It's probably tempered, but if not that's easy and should be inexpensive. Otherwise it just comes down to good carpentry done with care.

Comment: Yeah, judging by the shenanigans to get that glass to work, probably tempered. I take for granted a couple of local shops that will cut untempered within a 30 minute time frame, where maybe access to glass cutting or time of day rationalized the odd hack. I just looked at a 2012 IBC with commentary, and untempered is definitely allowed for the transom's glass. I can imagine using tempered glass for added quality or out of discomfort with the code, but I would quickly revisit that decision when faced with this situation. Maybe everything-tempered was a selling point with the customer.